# Safari - third party cookies

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage

Safari (8+) doesn't allow to read and store data from third party by default.
the setting for cookies is: "allow websites I visit".

I read some users that wrote a solution for this issue..

Explanation of this issue is found here:

http://measurablewins.gregjxn.com/2014_02_01_archive.html

This is a function that I used:

```
window.onload=function(){
   if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari')!=-1 && 
      navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')==-1){
        var cookies=document.cookie;
        if(top.location!=document.location){
           if(!cookies){
               href=document.location.href;
               href=(href.indexOf('?')==-1)?href+'?':href+'&';
               top.location.href = href+'reref='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
           }
        } else {
               ts=new Date().getTime();document.cookie='ts='+ts;
               rerefidx=document.location.href.indexOf('reref=');
               if(rerefidx!=-1){
                    href=decodeURIComponent(document.location.href.substr(rerefidx+6));
                    window.location.replace(href);
               }
        }
   }
}
```

The function is called and behaves as expected.

If the other domain is X that contains an iframe from my domain Y,

When I visit X, I don't see my domain in "Storage" tab on safari (although there was a redirect to my domain and back to the referer).

So I don't succeed to get the cookies that are found in my domain (from the domain Y).

Doesn't redirect to and back enable this third party? (my domain).